# unit test + snow leopard + xcode 3.2.2

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode

I have been trying to set breakpoint in my unit test code using SenTestCase framework in xcode 3.2.2. I can see the build results properly but unable to set a breakpoint.

Anyone having an idea please help.

Comment: Hey, I have been able to debug - now as a next step can anyone guide me how to write test cases? 
I have taken a look at the sample code 'iPhoneUnitTests', can anyone provide me links to more sample projects with unit tests?

Comment: I am unable to initialize my view controller in unit test class. I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception on trying to initialize it. Howevever I am able to initialize an NSobject. Any idea where I might my doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Matt Gallagher's sample iPhone app with unit tests](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/12/sample-iphone-application-with-complete.html), particularly the section titled "Debugging setup for the LogicTests target". The setup is a bit involved, but will save you a ton of time over the long run.

Additionally, [this article](http://www.grokkingcocoa.com/how_to_debug_iphone_unit_te.html) has some examples of common errors you may run into in the process, and how to fix them.